# Django testrunner failing with IntegrityError

Tags: django

When trying to run Django tests, the process fails seemingly on the admin post migrate signal. I can't find anything about this particular error. It appears that the signal is attempting to create a permission record that already exists - but I haven't modified anything with this particular model.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/app_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_permission_content_type_id_codename_01ab375a_uniq"
    DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id, codename)=(1, view_logentry) already exists.
```

Installed apps:

```
Installed apps:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'admin_view_permission',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.messages',
# Disable Django's own staticfiles handling in favour of WhiteNoise, for
# greater consistency between gunicorn and `./manage.py runserver`. See:
# http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
'rest_framework_xml',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'rest_auth.registration',
'django_extensions',
'django_celery_beat',
'django_celery_results',
'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
'corsheaders']
```

I don't have any test classes set up yet, which is why this error is particularly puzzling.

Comment: You need to provide more details on how you setup the test (the test class), the `INSTALLED_MODULES` that might influence the migrations, the models being tested and how you run the test, and if you are using fixtures.

Comment: Updated to add installed apps, no fixtures or test classes yet.

Comment: What is `admin_view_permission`? I suppose `view_logentry` is a permission used by `django.contrib.admin` and some other INSTALLED_APP tries to create it, as well. And `admin_view_permission` looks suspicious like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove `admin_view_permission` from your `INSTALLED_APPS`, this package is deprecated for Django 2.1